# Reading 3rd data data from excel using HSSF

Tags: selenium, apache-poi

I am trying to read the excel data, there are 2 data exist in the excel but my program is trying to read 3rd data which is null. Can some one please help me on this. below is my code.

```
public static Object[][] readExcel(String filePath, String sheetName)
        throws IOException {
    String[][] sheetData = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    sheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);
    int k, l;
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
    System.out.println(rowCount);
    int readRowCount = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
    Row r = sheet.getRow(1);
    int totalCol = r.getLastCellNum();
    System.out.println(totalCol);
    sheetData = new String[rowCount + 1][totalCol];
    k = 0;
    for (int i = readRowCount + 1; i <= rowCount; i++, k++) {
        l = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < totalCol; j++, l++) {
            try {
                sheetData[k][l] = getCellData(i, j);
                System.out.println(sheetData[k][l]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return (sheetData);
}

public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {
    try {
        Cell = sheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
        String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
        return CellData;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Q40.png)

Comment: ok..got the solutions..